# difference between comparisons using type(of: ) and isMember(of: )

Tags: swift

I am trying to look for instance of specific class in array of different classes (looking for index of specific ViewController in TabBarViewController)

I have a code that checks type using type(of: ) but it doesn't work:

```
func getTabIndex(_ rootClass: AnyClass) -> Int? {

    if let tabVC = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        for (index, vc) in tabVC.viewControllers!.enumerated() {
            if type(of: vc) == rootClass {
                return index
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

`if type(of: vc) == rootClass` always returns false.

When I change `if type(of: vc) == rootClass` to `vc.isMember(of: rootClass)` it works fine.

I assume isMember(of: ) is obj-c method while type(of: ) is pure swift, but I don't see why it would make difference on UIViewController.

Could somebody explain why type(of: ) doesn't work in this case? In both cases, I am comparing exact types, not the subclasses. TabBar has instances of FooViewController and BarViewController. When I call `getTabIndex(FooViewController.self)` I get nil when using type(of: ) and 0 when using isMember(of: )

**EDIT:**
I am aware that tpye(of: ) checks for exact type while kind(of: ) checks for subclasses as well, but in my case, I was checking exact type, so type(of: ) should be working fine, hence the confusion.

When I printed result of type(of: ) it was exactly same as when I printed value of rootClass. I know this only means that their textual representation is same and underlying types might be different, but I don't understand why that would be case

**EDIT2:**

Original question used isKind(of:) method which was misleading, I changed it to isMember(of: ) to reflect more closely source of my confusion, that is why type(of: ) doesn't work when comparing exact types

Comment: From the docs for [isKind(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418511-iskind): `true if the receiver is an instance of aClass or an instance of any class that inherits from aClass, otherwise false.`

Comment: _nomen est omen_, `UITabBarController` is __type of__ `UITabBarController` but __not type of__ `UIViewController` while it is a __kind of__ `UIViewController`.

Comment: I am not checking against UITabBarController, I am checking it's root view controllers and I am checking for exact type, so both methods should work fine, but for some reason, type(of) doesn't work

Comment: I realize now that title of the question and usage of kind(of: ) is misleading, I am not sure how to edit it to help tho

Comment: You say `if type(of: vc) == rootClass { ... }` doesn't work. But it works fine for me, precisely as you've shown it above (e.g. `let index = getTabIndex(FooViewController.self)` to find appropriate tab of tab bar controller). Generally you'd use `isKind(of:)`, anyway (in the spirit of Liskov substitution principle), but if you're asking why `type(of: vc)` isn't working, you'll need to give us a reproducible example of the problem, because it works fine for me. I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: hmm, that's good news I guess, I am not going crazy :) I will try to create simple example tomorrow, maybe I will find cause by stripping everything unnecessary

Comment: Issue is caused by one 3rd party library we are using. I am trying to find out what exactly in that library is causing it and will post answer once I get some tangible results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was cause by [Apptimize SDK](https://apptimize.com/). They are doing some shady stuff with classes for their UI editor to work. This results in changing type metadata for some classes (views, view controllers) and makes `type(of: )` return false even if comparing same types. `isMember(of: )` works because it's obj-c method and compares type in different, less rigorous way.

I suspect this can happen with other 3rd party libraries that try to be too clever as well, but in all other cases, `type(of: )` should be working without any issues

Answer (score 2):

### type(of:)

usage: `type(of: instance) == CheckingType.self`

return true **ONLY** when `instance` is exactly `CheckingType`

### isKind(of:)

this method is from stupid Objective-C and required `NSObjectProtocol` in swift use `instance is CheckingType`

usage: `instance.isKind(of: CheckingType.self)`

return true when `instance` is `CheckingType` or inherits from `CheckingType`

### is

Swift version of `isKind(of:)`

usage: `instance is CheckingType`

return true when `instance` is `CheckingType` or inherits from `CheckingType`

---

### Example

```
import Foundation

class Animal: NSObject { }
class Cat: Animal { }

Cat() is Cat // true
Cat() is Animal // true
Cat().isKind(of: Animal.self) // true
Cat().isKind(of: Cat.self) // true
type(of: Cat()) == Animal.self // false
type(of: Cat()) == Cat.self // true
```

Comment: With the example your answer is a bit more clear, but I think the textual explanation is still quite unclear about the difference between an _instance is matches CheckingType_ and _instance is exactly CheckingType_. I think it is important to state that you are talking about subclasses/inheritance.

Comment: I get this, but I was checking exact type and it was still returning false

Comment: @Lope Can you `print(type(of: vc))` and say what's printed?

Comment: sure, when I pass FooViewController instance, "FooViewController" gets printed. Exactly same thing as when I print out rootClass itself

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `isKind(of:)` is an Objective-C method that has been around since iOS2, while `type(of:)` is indeed a newer Swift method.

Moreover, they are used for different things. Even though in this use case you can achieve the same results using both, they are doing different things. `isKind(of:)` only return a `bool` indicating whether the receiver is an instance of the class in the parameter value or a class inheriting from that class, while `type(of:)` actually returns the dynamic type of the value. Using the latter, you don't have to have any information about the instance, you can still learn its type.

Reference: [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type), [isKind(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418511-iskind)

Comment: Than the documentation was misleading, thanks for the update, I will update my answer.

Comment: the `type(of:)` has been with us as `–isMemberOfClass:` since iOS2+.

Comment: @holex don't you mean `isKind(of:)`?

Comment: I meant `–isMemberOfClass:` exactly and precisely; that is what I have written above, have I? the `isKind(of:)` is the `–isKindOfClass:`, which has been with us since iOS2+ as well.

Comment: I thought you wanted to write `isKind(of:)` instead of `type(of:)`, but I realised that's not the case. However, as far as I'm concerned, `isMemberOfClass` isn't really a predecessor of `type(of:)`, since it only returns a boolean stating whether an instance is a member of a certain class, but it doesn't return the instance's dynamic type. Hence, it doesn't exactly do what `type(of:)` is doing.